# Vue 3 child component not receiving value

Tags: vue.js

Here's my main template:

```
{{ filteredResults.length }}
<results-count-filters :active-filters="activeFilters" :filtered-results-length="filteredResults.length"
  @update-filter="updateFilter"></results-count-filters>
```

Here's my child component 'results-count-filters':

```
export default {
  props: ['active-filters', 'filtered-results-length', 'query-string'],
  emits: ["updateFilter"],
  setup(props) {

    const { activeFilters, filteredResultsLength, queryString } = props

    return { 
      activeFilters, 
      filteredResultsLength,
      queryString
    }
  },
  template: `..... {{ filteredResultsLength }} .... {{ (new Date()).getTime() }}
    <div class="container">
      ...
    </div>`
}
```

Notice that I'm outputting the value of `filteredResults.length` in the parent template, then within the child I'm outputting filteredResultsLength (and unix time stamp just to prove it's re-rendering)

However, when the page is output it's showing:

```
4 ..... 0 .... 1710846399182
```

4 is the correct value, 0 is wrong, the long number is the unix time stamp that updates as expected. Why is the property value not set correctly in the child component? (should also be 4)

UPDATED

Here's my child component 'results-count-filters':

```
import {
  hasActiveFilters,
} from '../../functions'

export default {
  props: ['active-filters', 'filtered-results-length', 'query-string'],
  emits: ["updateFilter"],
  setup(props) {

    return { 
      hasActiveFilters
    }
  },
  template: `..... {{ filteredResultsLength }} .... {{ (new Date()).getTime() }}
    <div class="container">
      ...
    </div>`
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should never destructure props, since they loose reactivity:

```
// THAT'S WRONG!
const { activeFilters, filteredResultsLength, queryString } = props
```

The problem specifically is covered in the docs:

https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactive-props-destructure

> Similar to .value, you need to always access props as props.x in order to retain reactivity. This means you cannot destructure defineProps because the resulting destructured variables are not reactive and will not update.

Btw props are automatically exposed to the template, so you don't need to return them from `setup()`. In your case since the setup doesn't contain any other logic, just remove it:

```
export default {
  props: ['active-filters', 'filtered-results-length', 'query-string'],
  emits: ["updateFilter"],
  template: `..... {{ filteredResultsLength }} .... {{ (new Date()).getTime() }}
    <div class="container">
      ...
    </div>`
}
```

You can though convert your props to refs reactively bound to the props with `toRefs()`:

https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities#torefs

```
import {toRefs} from 'vue';
export default {
  props: ['active-filters', 'filtered-results-length', 'query-string'],
  emits: ["updateFilter"],
  setup(props) {

    const { activeFilters, filteredResultsLength, queryString } = toRefs(props);

    return { 
      activeFilters, 
      filteredResultsLength,
      queryString
    }
  },
  template: `..... {{ filteredResultsLength }} .... {{ (new Date()).getTime() }}
    <div class="container">
      ...
    </div>`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't realise that. Migrating from v2 so still learning Composition API. Btw I've updated my post, the code at the bottom, I have a function I still need to pass to the template so I'm guessing I still need setup() for that, but I've removed the prop deconstruction and it all works now.

Comment: @Martyn glad to help, if my answer resolved your question don't hesitate to accept it (the gray checkbox), thanks